# How can I view a text representation of an lxml element?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

If I'm parsing an XML document using lxml, is it possible to view a text representation of an element? 
I tried to do :

```
print repr(node)
```

but this outputs

```
<Element obj at b743c0>
```

What can I use to see the node like it exists in the XML file? Is there some `to_xml` method or something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation

```
>>> root = etree.XML('<root><a><b/></a></root>')

>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root><a><b/></a></root>'

>>> print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True))
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root><a><b/></a></root>

>>> print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='iso-8859-1'))
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<root><a><b/></a></root>

>>> print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
<root>
  <a>
    <b/>
  </a>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was driving me crazy :D

Comment: In Python 3, it looks nicer if you `decode` from `bytes`: `print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode()))`